# Vue JS hide src value in a iframe

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I've this code snippet. I want to protect my src value as much as possible. Yes I know I can't 100% protect the src value. I did

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

for disable right clicking. What are the other thing I could do for make my security level up?

I tired to encode my URL to data uri and embed in my code

```
<iframe src="data:text/uri-list;charset=utf-8;base64,aHR0cHM6Ly9wbGF5ZXIudmltZW8uY29tL3ZpZGVvLzc2OTc5ODcx"
     width="640" 
     height="360" 
     frameborder="0" 
     allow="autoplay; fullscreen" 
     allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

But this seems not working.

Comment: First of all, this is "security by obscurity" - which was discussed like a million times before so I will not get into this. Second, is there any user interaction before the video starts to play? Maybe you could offload the whole src into another part of your application